# Execute Oracle Script from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, oracle, plsql

So I would like to execute an oracle plsql script from Visual Studio.  I installed [Oracle's visual studio tools](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html) and opened up a new query window in VS2010 connected to an oracle db instance.  Here's a sample script that I'm trying to run:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Hello World!'); --tried various types of statements here
END;
```

and no matter what I try to put into the body of the begin/end block I get the following:

```
ERROR
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

I don't get the same issue when running from other tools like sql developer or toad.  What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've added the new line character after `END;`, i.e. line no. 4 must *not* be the last one:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Hello World!'); --tried various types of statements here
END; -- press Enter here
```

Oracle data client (`Oracle.DataAccess.Client`) is really picky about that.

**Update:** As I suspected, the problem had to do with line endings. It turns out that Oracle does not accept the `\r` (`0x0d`) characters within PL/SQL script blocks (but seems to ignore them when processing normal SQL), yet the Query window uses standard Windows line endings `\r\n` (`0x0d 0x0a`), and this is exactly what causes the problem.

I used [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what's transferred over the wire when I hit `Execute Query` toolbar button and when I select `Menu -> Tools -> Execute SQL *Plus Script` menu item. The result is strange, but predictable: Execute Query sends the query text *as-is* (and I got `PLS-00103`), while Execute SQL *Plus Script *does* translate `\r\n` to `\n` (The command(s) successfully completed.)

So it seems you've got these options:

1. Execute your script blocks via Menu -> Tools -> Execute SQL *Plus Script
2. Save your script to a disk drive using any editor capable of using Unix-style line endings, *then* open it from the Query window (it preserves the line endings in *existing* files, I checked)
3. Use something a bit more intelligent than Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (I prefer this option myself)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not make a difference.

Comment: You are right.  There is another option to use a VS plugin that strips CRs but I couldn't get it to work: http://grebulon.com/software/stripem.php

Answer (score 1):

Declare must have a identifier/variable, Since you do not have any, remove the declare statement.

Comment: Removing DECLARE makes no difference.  The error is still there.